# StartX fail in chroot

Tags: debian, android, chroot

I have Debian in my sdcard(as parition) and I mount it to my Android using Linux Deploy(it is an app that creates chroot environment). So,what is the problem?
Problem is about `startx`. I want to install and run `xfce4` in it but fails. Here is `Xorg.log`:

```
[ 17067.219] X.Org X Server 1.20.4 X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 17067.219] Build Operating System: Linux 4.19.0-16-armmp-lpae armv7l Debian
[ 17067.219] Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.10.49-10923522 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 23 15:47:22 KST 2018 armv7l
[ 17067.219] Kernel command line: boot_cpus=0,1,2,3,4 sched_enable_hmp=1 console=null androidboot.hardware=qcom user_debug=23 msm_rtb.filter=0x3F ehci-hcd.park=3 androidboot.bootdevice=7824900.sdhci androidboot.sec_atd.tty=/dev/ttyHSL0 loglevel=4 sec_log=0x100000@0xafe00008 sec_dbg=0x80000@0xaff00008 androidboot.revision=8 androidboot.warranty_bit=1 androidboot.bootloader=A700HXXS1CRJ4 lpm_levels.sleep_disabled=1 fg_reset=0 androidboot.boot_recovery=0 sec_debug.reset_reason=0x7 androidboot.debug_level=0x4f4c sec_debug.enable=0 sec_debug.enable_user=0 androidboot.cp_debug_level=0x55FF sec_debug.enable_cp_debug=0 vmalloc=340M uart_dbg=0 cordon=c538ddb1a6025c531bb59623c368fa3e connie=SM-A700H_OPEN_EUR_43ffad71f8256ed5bb00f7cb5217a4b9 lcd_id=0x420111 androidboot.security_mode=1526595584 androidboot.emmc=true androidboot.serialno=fa1bdc5f androidboot.baseband=msm lcd_id=0x420111 mdss_mdp.panel=1:dsi:0:ss_dsi_panel_S6E3FA2_AMS549EH01_FHD:1:none
[ 17067.220] Build Date: 19 April 2021  09:34:38AM
[ 17067.220] xorg-server 2:1.20.4-1+deb10u3 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[ 17067.220] Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
[ 17067.220]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 17067.221] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting, (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational, (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 17067.221] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Dec 11 09:55:40 2021
[ 17067.222] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 17067.223] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[ 17067.223] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 17067.223] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 17067.223] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 17067.225] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section". Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 17067.225] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 17067.225] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 17067.225] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 17067.225] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[ 17067.225] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[ 17067.225]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 17067.225] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[ 17067.225] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 17067.225] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices. If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[ 17067.225] (II) Loader magic: 0xb6fbff98
[ 17067.225] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 17067.225]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 17067.225]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[ 17067.225]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[ 17067.225]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[ 17067.248] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to get session: Failed to setup environment correctly
[ 17067.248] (II) no primary bus or device found
[ 17067.248] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 17067.249] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 17067.268] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 17067.268]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[ 17067.268]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[ 17067.268] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[ 17067.268] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[ 17067.268] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[ 17067.268] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[ 17067.268] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[ 17067.269] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 17067.269]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.20.4
[ 17067.269]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 17067.269]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[ 17067.269] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[ 17067.269] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[ 17067.270] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 17067.270]    compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 0.5.0
[ 17067.270]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 17067.270]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[ 17067.270] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[ 17067.270] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[ 17067.270] (EE) Fatal server error:
[ 17067.270] (EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot find a free VT: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[ 17067.271] (EE) 
[ 17067.271] (EE) Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help. 
[ 17067.271] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[ 17067.271] (EE) 
[ 17067.272] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: KDSETMODE failed: Bad file descriptor
[ 17067.272] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_GETMODE failed: Bad file descriptor
[ 17067.272] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I tried to use `nodm` but it doesn't seem to be working. How can I solve this problem and run `xfce`?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that you cant run xorg in android itself. So,you can just use vncserver to share screen and work. If u have any question or something else,feel free to comment.